Intuition abount countable compactness
In the context of direct method for calculus of variations, it is useful to introduce the notion of countably compact space, more explicitly:
Def: Let $K$ topological space, $K$ is countably compact iff every sequence in $K$ admit at least one cluster point in $K$.
Obviously every sequentially compact subspace is countably compact, but for the reverse we need first countability.
Someone have some usefull intuition about this notion of compactness?


Not "almost one" (which makes no sense), but at least one. 2) Did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countably_compact_space? 3) Your ambient space $X$ is useless. Apply directly your definition to the topological space $K$, and similarly for your "Obviously every sequentially compact subset is countably compact": replace "subset" by "space".

